# cant load more than 100 words in json android from sql

Tags: php, json

i have issues error when i am trying to load more than 100 words in json..

this is my code php

```
$result = array();
$query = "SELECT id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,100)deskripsi_lw,
                 latitude_lw,longitude_lw,nama_p,nama_k,
                 status_lw,gambar_lw
          from lokasi_wisata 
            JOIN kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten 
            JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi 
          WHERE nama_k LIKE '%$namekab%' 
          GROUP BY judul_lw  " ;
$res = mysql_query($query);

while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $result[] = $fetch;
}
// print_r($result);
echo mysql_error();
echo json_encode(array('res'=>$result)); :
```

when i changed left(deskripsi_lw,100)deskripsi_lw into 200 or more .. the result is nothing ..

the type data of deskripsi_lw is TEXT on my sql

Comment: I think this is problem with php not android

Comment: Do you get an error? If so show it to us

Comment: Have you checked your php error logs?

Comment: Maybe you have just exceeded PHP's memory limit ??

Comment: when i changed into 200 , i cant see anything in my web browser.. not error ..

Comment: @Muhammad Muqorrobin I think you should test this querry in mysql datatabase first

Comment: Remove the `echo mysql_error();`, does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still works if you use 
sout in java